# get only one row of the same name, index, amount but different code

Tags: sql, select, distinct

I've got the query:

```
select distinct index, name, code, amount as amount_min 
from sales s 
where (amount = 
(
    select mindex(s1.amount) 
    from sales s1 
    where  s1.name = s.name
)) 
order by s.name
```

Query works very well, but I would like to modify them so that when the column index, code, amount in several rows are identical, only one show, the first row. The rest (although different code columns) should be ignored. Can someone help me?

Comment: If you need consistency, you will need to define what you mean by "first" row. Otherwise you can query from the result of your current query and add a "row number" (Oracle would be ROWNUM) column, and have your wrapping select choose the row with the MIN row number.

Comment: Please post a short sample of what you are currently getting and what you would like to get. If you can include the relevant table structure as well, it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know if it's oracle, sql server, sybase ase, etc., you way to do it is like this:

**Step 1:** insert the data in a temporary table with an identity column

```
select distinct counter = identity(10), index, name, code, amount as amount_min
into #t1
from sales s 
where (amount = 
(
    select mindex(s1.amount) 
    from sales s1 
    where  s1.name = s.name
)) 
order by s.name
```

**Step 2:** make the needed select

```
select index, name, code, amount_min from #t1
where counter in (select min(counter) from #t1 group by index, name, amount_min)
```

**Step 3:** drop the temporary table

```
drop table #t1
```